# How to write unit test for Controller with multiple modelattribute

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a unit test for my controller but I need help,there is two modelAttribute as enum outside of my controller to use in all my controllers so  this is my code.please help me I'm new in test unit.

```
@Autowired
private MaintenanceService maintenanceService;

@ModelAttribute("departments")
public List<Department> getDepartments(){
    return Arrays.asList(Department.values());
}

@ModelAttribute("servicetypes")
public List<ServiceType> getServiceTypes(){
    return Arrays.asList(ServiceType.values());
}

@GetMapping("/ListOfMaintenance")
public String showListOfMaintenancePage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("maintenance",new Maintenance());
    model.addAttribute("Maintenances",maintenanceService.retriveListOfMaintenance());
    return "List_Of_Maintenance";
}
```

Comment: Look at the Spring `MockMvc` feature.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) can help you.

The `@WebMvcTest` annotation on a test class tells spring not to bring up all the application's details, but only those related to the API, in your case your `Controller`s. In addition, it provides you with a handy tool - `MockMvc` class, which you can use to "shoot" requests towards your controllers, as if they were actual HTTP calls. You can also assert the output of those calls, to validate if what you expect your controller should be doing is actually what it did. Take a look:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class WebLayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello World")));
    }
}
```